# containsOnlyElementsOf returning false on passing two objects

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I am writing cucumber test cases which uses jUnit as test runner. I am using method to assert true if both objects have same elements.

```
assertThat(obj1).containsOnlyElementsOf(obj2)
```

But, it's not returning true even though both objects have exactly the same elements and same values. Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
<[com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@e12becd7,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@4543a8b3,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@c08e2719,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@d298d9da]>
to contain only:
<[com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@6276a018,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@ed39d0fe,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@7bda09e9,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@673947a0]>
elements not found:
<[com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@6276a018,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@ed39d0fe,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@7bda09e9,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@673947a0]>
and elements not expected:
<[com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@e12becd7,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@4543a8b3,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@c08e2719,
com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.dto.TimesheetListRowDto@d298d9da]>

at                      com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.steps.TimesheetSteps.i_get_the_following_timesheet   s(TimesheetSteps.java:806)
at ✽.Then I get the following timesheets: (com/solambda/kronos/timesheet/Worker_list.feature:43)
```

Have anyone ever faced the similar issue. Let me know if anywhere I am missing something or not doing things properly.

Comment: These assertion methods usually work by comparing the elements (`TimesheetListRowDto`) with their `equals` method. How is the `equals` method of `TimesheetListRowDto` implemented?

Comment: @ThomasKläger using EqualsBuilder() from apache commons.

Comment: yes. issue was with equals method. It should be implemented properly for this method to work

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `assertj-core` as library for the method `containsOnlyElementsOf`!?

This method `containsOnlyElementsOf` does check if the iterables do have the **same** objects, not only if they are equal!